# My drawable is not drawn after orientation change (using loadermanager)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-loadermanager

I'm using the loadermanager for my app. On Orientation change my app can reload the TextView, but the imagestream for my drawable is not loaded the second time. On the first load the picture shows ,but after an orientation change it stays in its unchanged state. (in my case , a white square)

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Person> loader, Person p) {
    tvProfileName.setText(p.getName()); 

    Log.i("img stream", ""+p.getImageStream());
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(p.getImageStream());
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b);
    ivMenuPhoto.setImageDrawable(d);
}
```

The setText is working and my name is loaded, even after the orientation change. But the setimagedrawable is not working. The p.getImageStream is not null...

Is my drawable maybe set before the layout is finished changing? I'm just very confused, because my TextView is working.

edited for my solution:

I added a Drawable attribute in the Person Object. So the loader can also hold that part. Then I created the getters and setters. And then I added the onResume to also set my drawable after the orientation change

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Person> loader, Person p) {
    tvProfileName.setText(p.getName()); 

    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), p.getPersonphoto());
    this.personPhoto = d;
    ivMenuPhoto.setImageDrawable(d);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    ivMenuPhoto.setImageDrawable(this.personPhoto);
}
```

Comment: That's because after the orientation change the method `OnResume()` is called. You should check there (in the `OnResume()` method) if a pervious `onLoadFinished()` has been executed (via a flag variable) and then put the same code in the `if` statement as in the `onLoadFinished()` method.

Comment: thanks, I'm setting the image in the onresume method. And its working now!

Comment: Shall I post an answer?

Comment: I edited my post. I don't know if it's the right way... but it is working. If you could tell me your answer, then of course I would very much appreciate it :)